# RewriteRule for all .php pages with constant querystring

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm working on a project which all pages need to have a querystring assumed id. for example following pages:

1. example.com/alfa.php?id=1
2. example.com/beta.php?id=30
3. exapmle.com/gamma.php?id=50

I'm using the following .htaccess to make my URLs beautiful.

```
RewriteEngine On
## BEAUTIFUL URL
DirectoryIndex default.php
Options -Multiviews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
#RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash off
# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
# rewrite /dir/file?query to /dir/file.php?query
RewriteRule ^([\w\/-]+)(\?.*)?$ $1.php$2 [L,T=application/x-httpd-php]
```

This code will make the following convertion:

`example.com/alfa.php?id=1 to example.com/alfa?id=1`

Assuming that X.php is everytime changing (X) but id is always constant, What is the best content of .htaccess file?

I tried several methods, But what is the best?

and one thing more, How can I convert URL into `example.com/alfa/1` AND `example.com/beta/30`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to match against the query string (all the stuff after `?`) in the regex pattern of your rule. The query string isn't part of that match, only the URI. But since you don't want the query string to be touched, just don't match against it since it'll get appended automatically:

```
RewriteEngine On
## BEAUTIFUL URL
DirectoryIndex default.php
Options -Multiviews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
#RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash off
# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1 [R=301,L]
# rewrite /dir/file?query to /dir/file.php?query
RewriteRule ^([\w/-]+)$ $1.php [L,T=application/x-httpd-php]
```

For `example.com/alfa/1` and `example.com/beta/30`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [A-Z]{3,9}\ /([\w/-]+)(\.php)?\?id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%3 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([\w/-]+?)/([0-9]+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA,T=application/x-httpd-php]
```

Something else you can try doing is getting rid of your rules and just using `Multiviews`, which you have turned off. Multiviews and mod_negotiation was made for stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to convert it to `example.com/alfa/1`

Comment: Dear Jon Lin, I tried to use your second code. But I get the NOT FOUND error when I try `example.com/alfa/1`